# 504 error when opening jupyterlab notebook in google cloud after adding disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, jupyter-lab

I have a jupyter notebook instance in GCP which worked fine. When importing my data, I got the error that the machine did not have enough space so I added a disk with 500 GB in its default mode.

Now when I try to open jupyterlab, I get this error:

```
504. That’s an error.

That’s all we know.
```

Tried adding a firewall for jupyter, did not change anything. Also tried to delete the disk again, but I'm still not able to access jupyterlab. How can I access Jupyterlab again? I'm not very familiar with gcp and sdk, so I'd rather not use the cloud shell to do my calculations in Python.

Comment: Have you considered rebooting the instance after you added the disk? I would also check the serial logs of the VM to see if there are additional error messages. If you're able to SSH into the VM then you can try to restart the service '~$sudo service jupyter restart'.

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the disk space. I normally get that error when I've ran out of disk space.

Comment: 100GB is not sufficient?